# Increment json values using Python

Tags: python, json

I am developing an MQTT client that is publishing to the topic "city/place" and sends data in a json object format to a MQTT broker.

I am having a structure data misunderstanding.

MY json object looks like this:

```
people = {'man': 31, 'women': 31, 'date': 23/11/15, 'city': "Moscu"}
```

For some reason I need to increment every second the number of people that comes to Moscu.

Here is my full code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import time

mqttc = mqtt.Client('python_publisher')
mqttc.connect('127.0.0.1', 1883)

people = {'man': 31, 'women': 31, 'date': 23/11/15, 'city': "Moscu"}

while True:
    people_json2str = json.dumps(people)
    print (people_json2str)
    mqttc.publish('city/place', people_json2str)
    people = {'man': 31 + 1, 'women': 31 + 1, 'date': 23/11/15, 'city': "Moscu"}
    time.sleep (1)
```

I parse the json to a string format because mqtt needs the data like this. Then I publish it into the topic "city/place".
After that I try to increment the json object values but it is not working like that.
Do you now a way to update the json values and parse them as a string using Python?

Comment: You're missing a call to `mqttc.loop_start()`. Without that, your background network traffic won't get processed. I'd put it right after the call to `connect()`.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
people = {'man': 31, 'women': 31, 'date': 23/11/15, 'city': "Moscu"}
```

is a [dictionary](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html).

You can access values from a dictionary by their keys:

```
>>> print people['man']
>>> 31
```

You can also change dictionary values just like you would change variables.

To increment `x=1`, you do `x+=1`. Analogously, you do

```
people['man'] +=1
```

to increase the integer "man" by one. The same applies to women.

By the way, I am surprised to see `23/11/15` without quotation marks (which would make it a string). What you are writing is `23 divided by 11 divided by 15`. That's surely not what you want :D

Comment: I just create the object people like that

Comment: @ferran Is that a question or a statement? Yes, you can initialize a dictionary like it was done in the second line of my answer.

Comment: @ferran  `23/11/15` yields the integer `0`; `'23/11/15'` is a string that could be converted to a date.

Comment: I get it now, you were referring to the question in the last line of my answer. @decitype_auto made the right comment regarding that topic.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
people = {'man': 31 + 1, 'women': 31 + 1, 'date': '23/11/15', 'city': "Moscu"}
```

creates a new dictionary every second with `man` and `woman` set to `32`  instead of incrementing the respective last value want you apparently want to do.

Comment: You are rigth, that's exactly what happens. I need to increment the value every second

Comment: @ferran But if you already know that it doesn't achieve what you want, why do you do it? To increment sth you need to have `+= 1` act on a reference; and the respective references, most obviously, are `people['man']` and  `people['women'] `.

Comment: @ferran: Btw - the plural of 'man' is 'men', and the 'date' field should be populated with sth that can at least be converted to the date you want to enter, e.g. with the string I used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at how to access python dictionaries

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import time

mqttc = mqtt.Client('python_publisher')
mqttc.connect('127.0.0.1', 1883)

people = {'man': 31, 'women': 31, 'date': 23/11/15, 'city': "Moscu"}

while True:
    people_json2str = json.dumps(people)
    print (people_json2str)
    mqttc.publish('city/place', people_json2str)
    people['man'] = people['man'] + 1
    people['women'] = people['woman'] + 1 
    time.sleep (1)
```

Comment: Thanky tou I need to check it !

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .**contains** . This is for those who wish to convert their table value into key.

```
jsondata = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if jsondata.__contains__(row['Vehicle']):
        jsondata[row['Vehicle']] += 1
    else:
        jsondata[row['Vehicle']] = 1


print(jsondata)
```

If you want to have your parent key and child key has the same table value, you can also do this.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    if jsondata.__contains__(row['Vehicle']):
        jsondata[row['Vehicle']][row['Vehicle']] += 1
    else:
        jsondata[row['Vehicle']]={}
        jsondata[row['Vehicle']][row['Vehicle']] = 1


print(jsondata)
```